# How to create a new data frame by removing specific values in a column?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with several columns, what I would like to do is to create a new dataset/frame by simply excluding entries based on if a column is a certain value

I've searched up similar questions yet proven to be unsuccessful I'm trying to achieve this in base R, so far I've tried using brackets and subset function. You can see below what I've attempted.

````
newdata<-dataset[dataset5$occupation!=c(2,3,4)```

I anticipated this would return the original dataset, with the exception that all entries where the column 'occupation' = 2,3,4 would be removed
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `%in%` and then negate (`!`)

```
dataset[!dataset5$occupation %in% c(2,3,4),]
```

or with `subset`

```
subset(dataset, !occupation %in% 2:4)
```

---

The `==` or `!=` works when there is only a single value to compare.  If it is more and not equal to the number of rows, then this gets recycled i.e. 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, ... until it reach the end of 'occupation' i.e. it will check by position and this is not what is needed.  Instead with `%in%`, it checks the values anywhere in the column giving a `TRUE/FALSE` output and with negate (`!`), this gets reversed to `FALSE/TRUE`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!